# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroups returns only one group "Domain User" for some users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, directoryservices, userprincipal

The code below was working a few weeks ago, but recently it stopped getting the groups for many user accounts, and I can't figure out what changed. The code has not changed.

The `.GetGroups()` method is only returning one group, ***Domain User*** for many of the users on the domain, but for my user, and a couple of others it does return the full collection of groups.

The goal is simply to get a list of groups that this user belongs to. I don't know much about the Active Directory structure.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Emply.Username))
    if (user != null)
    { 
        foreach (var gn in user.GetGroups())
        {
            groups += gn.Name + "|";
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's your question ? Maybe the your code is right, the listed users have only one group. Did you check your AD ?

Comment: At this point, I think you are correct and the code is right, but I'm getting a permissions issue with Active Directory. I know the users have groups in AD that the code is not returning. Unfortunately I now have to wait for my IT department to test this.

Comment: I want to add in 2017 I've also experienced this issue.  For me I can enumerate all groups on my workstation and on the server when running as administrator (logged on to the same account with both machines).  But when running normally on the server I can only see the first group in a user's account.  Hopefully someone will come along and find those details useful.